# sort records by status and datetime asc or desc

Tags: mysql

Guide me here, if you can:
I'm using mysql.

I need to order Events according to the sequence:

1. the ones that are happening: status = started
   (and datetime ASC)

```
2021-12-07 07:00:00 | started
2021-12-07 08:00:00 | started
2021-12-07 09:00:00 | started
```

2. the ones that will happen: status = created
   (and datetime asc)

```
2021-12-07 13:00:00 | created
2021-12-07 14:00:00 | created
2021-12-07 15:00:00 | created
```

3. those that have passed the date but have not started
   (and datetime desc)

```
2021-12-07 06:00:00 | created
2021-12-07 05:00:00 | created
2021-12-07 04:00:00 | created
```

4. the finished ones: status = finished
   (and datetime desc)

```
2021-12-06 12:00:00 | finished
2021-12-05 17:00:00 | finished
2021-12-04 19:00:00 | finished
```

I'm trying with some CASE WHEN...

```
order by
  CASE
    WHEN E.status = 'started' THEN 1
    WHEN E.status = 'created' && eventDateTime >= NOW() THEN 2
    WHEN E.status = 'created' && eventDateTime < NOW() THEN 3
    WHEN E.status = 'finished' THEN 4
    ELSE 5
  END
```

But I didn't know how to match `THEN 1 && eventDateTime ASC`
or `THEN 4 && eventDateTime DESC`

Comment: In this case the simplest is to just append `,IF(E.status = 'started', eventDateTime ASC, eventDateTime DESC)` . but it also sorts 2 and 3 by datetime desc (but you could flip that.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try (because i have not done so meself):

```
order by
  CASE
    WHEN E.status = 'started' THEN 1
    WHEN E.status = 'created' && eventDateTime >= NOW() THEN 2
    WHEN E.status = 'created' && eventDateTime < NOW() THEN 3
    WHEN E.status = 'finished' THEN 4
    ELSE 5
  END,
  CASE
    WHEN E.status = 'started' THEN eventDateTime
    WHEN E.status = 'created' && eventDateTime >= NOW() THEN eventDateTime
    WHEN E.status = 'created' && eventDateTime < NOW() THEN -eventDateTime
    WHEN E.status = 'finished' THEN -eventDateTime
    ELSE eventDateTime 
  END
```

I might have put the `-` signs in the wrong place.... (sorry)

EDIT: After testing, because of the comments , I noticed that I made an error. the working solution is like this:

see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8643333cefbb66faf46738b3424aac12)

This is working because I am sorting on a numeric value (while the original answer was not sorting on a numeric value).

```
SELECT
   eventDateTime,
   status
FROM table1 E
order by
  CASE
    WHEN E.status = 'started' THEN 1
    WHEN E.status = 'created' && eventDateTime >= NOW() THEN 2
    WHEN E.status = 'created' && eventDateTime < NOW() THEN 3
    WHEN E.status = 'finished' THEN 4
    ELSE 5
  END,
  CASE
    WHEN E.status = 'started' THEN 0+eventDateTime
    WHEN E.status = 'created' && eventDateTime >= NOW() THEN 0+eventDateTime
    WHEN E.status = 'created' && eventDateTime < NOW() THEN -eventDateTime
    WHEN E.status = 'finished' THEN -eventDateTime
    ELSE 0+eventDateTime 
  END
```

Comment: How do you "minus" a datetime?

Comment: see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5876e516f48ac8ae32aaa97abfa76b4d)   This relies on the fact that MySQL will turn `2021-01-03 00:00:00` into `-20210103000000` when a minus sign is added.

Comment: Ahh... a trick!

Comment: But this does not work. now the comparison is `2021-01-03 00:00:00`(DATETIME) against `-20210103000000`(DATE) mysql wil not order this correctly, you got to make sure that both are integers first. or date format. (I tested this)

Comment: @Firewizz: now I tried my answer..... (I will edit the answer in a moment)

Comment:  it works nicely!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way is to do this, but it is just a matter of preference if you ask me;

```
ORDER BY 
    -- First order by status
    FIELD(E.status, 'started', 'created', 'finished'), 

    -- If status is created, order by isHistory 
    IF(E.status = 'created', eventDateTime < NOW(), 0),

    -- Lastly order by the datetime asc or desc depending on state
    IF(E.Status IN('created','finished'), -eventdatetime, ABS(-eventdatetime))
```

A small addition, while i was testing this I noticed if the datetime columns are strings you need some converting, you need to replace the last part with:

```
IF( E.Status IN('created','finished'), 
    (-CAST(eventdatetime AS DATETIME)), 
    ABS(-CAST(eventdatetime AS DATETIME))
)
```

Note the ABS usage to make sure both eventdatetimes are treated as integers. Other options are casting to INT/unsigned or 0+eventdatetime.

*Another thing you could do is add the CASE you already have to the select and order by that first. This way you could just select the part you need.*